# How to get htaccess redirect for non-www to https?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to have an htaccess that does the following:

```
http://example.com redirect to: https://www.example.com
https://example.com redirect to: https://www.example.com
example.com redirect to https://www.example.com
www.example.com redirect to https://www.example.com
```

So basically every method of the url redirects to https://www.example.com

Thanks.

I used this but its not working for all instances above:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and make sure to clear your browser's cache before retesting.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Also, for some reason when I click on a modification in vbulletin (click on the link) it redirects back to my main forum page. I checked through a redirect online checker and it shows a 301 redirect from the url link back to my home page. Not sure why it is doing this. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Kirk not familiar with vbulletin, but you could try adding an additional condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST`

Comment: Here is what the mod writer wants in the htaccess file, but even he had someone else write it, and was not too sure, I'm not familiar with htaccess:

Comment: RewriteRule ^classifieds/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=main&catid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sale/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wanted/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^trade/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=seller&sellerid=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: @Kirk this has absolutely nothing to do with your question

Comment: Your suggestion worked great on the https redirect. Now just trying to figure out how to get the link within the forum to go to the page and not redirect back to the forum...

What does RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST  do? Does that affect the https? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be relevant since I am having both issues. Should I a start another question? Thanks.

Comment: Lin, one more question that maybe you can help me with. The code above (ozzmodz) I added BEFORE the redirect code you provided and now it seems to be working. What are your thoughts on this. Did I affect the redirect to the https for the site url at all? Thanks again!